# Html - Get value from database

Tags: c#, html, sql

So I want to get the `title`for that image in the database. How do I do it? It's showing `Describe your post...` for all images **instead of the actual title of the image in the database**

https://i.gyazo.com/17828889116a77983f70fd8c8a4c2ebf.png

View:

```
    @foreach (var image in Model.Images)
{
    <h2>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.title)</h2>
    <div class="row">       
        <div class="col-md-8 portfolio-item">
            <img class="portrait" src="@Url.Content(image)" alt="Hejsan" />
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

Model

```
 [Table("MemeImages")]
public class UploadFileModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string location { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Images { get; set; }

    public int contentLength { get; set; }
    public string contentType { get; set; }

    public string userID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Describe your post...")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    public void SavetoDatabase(UploadFileModel file)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();                    
        db.uploadedFiles.Add(file);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of label use directly `<h2>m => m.title</h2>`

Comment: That doesnt make sence.

Comment: It makes, assuming you want to show the VALUE of the property and not an arbitrary label. Well, also assuming that you correctly set the value from db

Answer (score 0):

Remove the display attribute.

```
[Required]
public string title { get; set; }
```

Also, LabelFor() is not the right thing. You may want to use Display/DisplayFor() to render the value.

Comment: If I doi `<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.title)</h2>` it doesnt show any title.